# Order list ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have a page with one list from a JSON file. What I want to do it's to add an order by funcionality. I don't understand yet if I need to use @Pipe or if there is a simpler way.
I'm planning to do it in a modal page.
Thanks in advance any help will be appreciated.
modalpage.html:

```
<ion-toolbar danger>
  <ion-buttons start>
    <button (click)="close()">
      <ion-icon ios="ios-close" md="md-close"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title  text-center>
    Ajustes
  </ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button (click)="applyFilters()">
      <ion-icon ios="ios-checkmark" md="md-checkmark"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>  
<ion-content padding class="rojo">
  <h2 text-center>Ordenar resultados por:</h2>
</ion-content>
```

modalpage.js

```
import {Page, NavController,ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/ajustes-listado/ajustes-listado.html',
})
export class AjustesListadoPage {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController],[ViewController]];
  }

  constructor(nav, viewController) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.viewCtrl = viewController;
  }

  close(data) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
  }
  applyFilters(){
    console.log('aplicando filtros a la lista');
    this.close();
  }
}
```

list.html

```
<ion-navbar *navbar danger>
    <ion-title text-center>Listado</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons start *ngIf="buscar==false">
    <button (click)="search()">
      <ion-icon ios="ios-search" md="md-search"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button (click)="options()">
      <ion-icon ios="ios-options" md="md-options"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
<ion-content class="listado">
      <ion-list [virtualScroll]="vets">
        <button ion-item text-wrap *virtualItem="let vet" (click)="goToDetails(vet)">
            <ion-avatar item-left>
                <!-- <ion-img [src]="vet.img || defaultImg"></ion-img> -->
                <img src="{{vet.img}}" onError="this.src='./files/gmaps.png';" />
            </ion-avatar>
            <h2>{{vet.nombre}}</h2>
            <p>Direccion: {{vet.direccion}}</p>
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

list.js

```
import {DetallesPage} from '../detalles/detalles';
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Page, NavController, Platform, NavParams, Modal} from 'ionic-angular';
import {MiServicio} from '../../providers/mi-servicio/mi-servicio';
import {AjustesListadoPage} from '../ajustes-listado/ajustes-listado';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/listado/listado.html',
  providers:[MiServicio]
})
export class ListadoPage {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController],[Platform],[MiServicio]];
  }

    constructor(nav,platform, miServicio) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.platform = platform;
    this.miServ = miServicio;
    this.ngOnInit();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.miServ.getVets().subscribe(
        data => this.vets = data
    );
  }    
}
```

Comment: This llink explains pretty well the pipe implementation for searching and sorting in array of objects: https://www.djamware.com/post/5a37ceaf80aca7059c142970/ionic-3-and-angular-5-search-and-sort-list-of-data

Answer (score 2):

Angular2 doesn't provide the orderBy filter (now "pipe") like angular 1 does.

> Angular does not ship with pipes for filtering or sorting lists. Developers familiar with Angular 1 know these as filter and orderBy. There are no equivalents in Angular 2.
>   
> refer: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filter-pipe

You'll need to sort the items in your component. The best option is always sort them on the server-side, but if you know there's only a few items or you really want to sort on the client-side, you can use the array.sort() method.

Examples and documentation:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

You said you have the list in a JSON file, so it's a persistent data isn't it? 
Take a look at this: [Sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) 
I think this will be the best option for you.